# How do you disable AUTH in sendmail?

Tags: security, sendmail

I'd like to entirely disable AUTH on my home server's sendmail on Fedora 21, mostly because the constant fail2ban Emails are annoying, coming from constant CRAM-MD5 brute force attempts to get my server to serve as a relay.  Disabling AUTH removes this whole category of attack.  What I'd like is that the only authorization for relaying is the file `/etc/mail/access`, and that my sendmail not even accept AUTH commands.

When I wireshark an SMTP connection or when I use telnet to test my sendmail, after EHLO it responds:

```
250-<hostname> Hello [<remote host>], pleased to meet you 
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-AUTH GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
```

My sendmail config has these commented out lines:

```
dnl TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
dnl define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
```

I'm wondering if simply configuring

```
TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`')dnl Empty list to disable auth
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `')dnl Empty list to disable auth
```

is sufficient.  I also wonder if there will be unexpected side effects, such as being unable to send mail to a server using AUTH.  I've tried to search for information about this, but I've only found people who want AUTH but can't get it working, and client problems with AUTH.  I don't want to assume that an empty list does what I want, and no documentation I've found says explicitly how to completely disable AUTH.

Edit:  I could disable fail2ban email notification (although I find it useful) or increase my ban time (good idea for AUTH as no legitimate connection will use it on my server).  I still want to disable AUTH.  I think I'm more secure if I do so.  If disabled, future bugs in this area won't be my security holes.

Comment: fail2ban doesn't send emails, unless you configure it to do something that involves sending emails. How about simply changing your fail2ban configuration to, say, block these hosts outright for a long period of time (on the order of days)?

Comment: I hit a bug earlier this year where fail2ban would crash.  Not seeing a single notification for 24 hours was a clear sign.  I think that's fixed, but the notifications are still useful as long as it's not from an unrelenting hacker who won't give up.  Good idea on increasing ban time for AUTH.  I updated the question to indicate why I think disabling AUTH is still a good idea.